# Can Scipy SmoothBivariateSpline deal with unknown/large numbers of knots (kx, ky)?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, smoothing, spline

I am getting some strange behaviour when running scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline. When running this with any smoothing factor apart from None the code seems to stall without an error message. I have run it on a server for around 3 days and it appears that I have got no outputs - could it actually just be taking this long?

I am trying to compute the smooth spline of a surface slightly less than 1000x1000 pixels:[image: Surface to find smooth spline of]

Interpolation with griddata works well for interpolation however I require a smoothing factor. Here is a recreation of the code, this will print "Completed with s=None" and then will stay running (for over 3 days) without computing any more splines. Am I using incorrect smoothing values, or am I using the function wrong? Here is a recreation of my problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothBivariateSpline

def smooth_2d_spline(frame, s):
    # sort out x and y, axies and grids
    frame = np.asarray(frame)
    x, y = frame.shape
    x_axis = np.arange(x-1, dtype=np.float64)
    y_axis = np.arange(y-1, dtype=np.float64)
    points = frame.nonzero()
    values = frame[points].reshape(len(points[0]))
    #I think stalling is caused by not knowing the spline knots
    spline = SmoothBivariateSpline(points[0], points[1], values, s=s)
    print('Calculated spline with: ' + str(s))
    smoothed_frame = spline.__call__(x_axis, y_axis)
    return smoothed_frame

def F(x, y):
    # a function that requires many knots
    return (np.sin(np.sqrt((3*x)**2 + (0.2*y)**2)))


fit_points = np.linspace(0, 850, 850), np.linspace(0, 850, 850)
frame = F(*np.meshgrid(*fit_points, indexing='ij'))
for s in [None, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100]:
    smooth_2d_spline(frame, s)
```

EDIT:

I now believe that the function is not computing because of an unrealistic amount of knots, for example the default is kx=3 and ky=3, and this obviously is not realistic for the surface.

If the number of knots is increased e.g. explicitly pass values kx=10 and ky=10 to the function I get an error:

> in **init** nx, tx, ny, ty, c, fp, wrk1, ier = dfitpack.surfit_smth(x, y, z, w, dfitpack.error: (1<=kx && kx<=5) failed for 6th keyword kx: surfit_smth:kx=10

Which I think means there are too many knots (>5). I cannot find anything in the documentation that states the knot limit. So I now have two more questions:

1. Is it possible to do a 2d spline interpolation without stating number of knots? - like I know it is with scipy's 1D function.
2. Is there any way to smooth 2D spline interpolate with kx and ky > 5?

Comment: Your example is not completely reproducible as you load from file, I generated a random 1000x1000 frame, and I receive `failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (-1809702896,)` on scipy 1.7 or 1.8.

Comment: So this is a Fortran integer overflow https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5064

Comment: @Bob Thanks for your comment, I believe that 1000x1000 runs into a memory error as the function is built on fortran (old and has fundamental memory limits). The example with 850x850 pixels should work. I have updated my code example to reflect this & also to be reproducable.

Answer (score 1):

`kx=ky=3` are not knot numbers, these are spline degrees: i.e., you are using cubic splines.

Changing `SmoothBivariateSpline` to `bisplrep` (same underlying Fortran code, a different wrapper) with an updated 850x850 example triggers the MemoryError on my machine, so it is an integer overflow indeed.

To your questions:

1. Yes, FITPACK based splines select knots automatically, and there is no control over the knot number and location. It's a known issue, improving the status quo is on the roadmap but no ETA.
2. FITPACK only allows spline degrees up to five. You *can* change the limit manually in the Fortran sources, which are in the `scipy/interpolate/fitpack` folder. You'll need to recompile scipy, and I have no idea what is the FITPACK behavior for higher order splines. YMMV

If you need interpolation not smoothing, prefer `RegularGridInterpolator` to *BivariateSplines.

EDIT: The memory error is triggered by this line: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/interpolate/src/_fitpackmodule.c#L300

```
lwa = 2*nmax + lcest + lwrk1 + lwrk2 + kwrk;
if ((wa = malloc(lwa*sizeof(double))) == NULL) {
    PyErr_NoMemory();
    goto fail;
}
```

To check the value of `lwa` I've dropped a breakpoint to the location indicated by the python traceback, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py#L956

```
 /home/br/repos/scipy/scipy/build-install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py(959)bisplrep()
-> tx, ty, c, o = _fitpack._surfit(x, y, z, w, xb, xe, yb, ye, kx, ky,
(Pdb) p lwrk1
1520310822
(Pdb) p lwrk2
864722401
```

So, your example (with `bisplrep` instead of `SmoothBivariateSpline` and `s=1e5`) tries to allocate a work array of size north of 12 Gb and unsurprisingly fails.

Your original code has I suspect the same error. You can of course check it by dropping a `print*,` statement into the `surfut.f` source and recompiling scipy, but I rather strongly suspect it's the culprit: in the end of the day both `bisplrep` and `SmoothBivariateSpline` call into `fitpack/surfit.f`.

So, the short answer is there is there does not seem to be a way FITPACK smoothing algorithm can handle this.

Comment: I see my ambiguity between spline degrees and knot number know, thank you. A cubic spline should be able to fit to that function - so is the reason I cannot compute the spline when s=0.5, for example, just because it is taking a massive amount of time (> a few days)? Or am I running into the mentioned memory error (without an error message)?

Comment: See the edited answer. AFAICS, the work arrays FITPACK tries to allocate are simply too huge to produce anything useful.